# If a harmonic function $u\colon G \to \mathbb{R}$ has a zero in $z_0\in G$, than there is another zero in every neighbourhood of $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a proof but I am not sure if it is right.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ with $U_{\epsilon}(z_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2)\subset G$. Let $p<\epsilon$. From the mean value property of $u$, it follows:

$0=u(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+ pe^{it})dt \Rightarrow \int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+ pe^{it})dt =0$

If $u=0$ on $\{z_0+ pe^{it}|t\in[0,2\pi]\}$ than we are done, so we assume $u\neq 0$ on $\{z_0+ pe^{it}|t\in[0,2\pi]\}$. Without loss of generality there is $t_1$ so that $u(z_0+ pe^{it_1})>0$. Because of the fact that the upper integral is zero, there has to be a $t_2$ with $u(z_0+ pe^{it_2})<0$. $u$ is harmonic and with that also continous. From the intermediate value theorem it follows that $\{u(z_0+ pe^{it})|t\in[0,2\pi]\}$ has to be connected $\Rightarrow$ there exists a $t_0$ with $u(z_0+ pe^{it_0})=0$.

Comment: proof more or less correct (not sure about intermediate value theorem here, but the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected, and in $\mathbb R$ this means the image is an interval) another proof on similar lines is to notice that because $u$ real and a punctured disc is connected, we get that $u$ sends any small disc centered at $z_0$ minus its center to a connected set in $\mathbb R$ so if there is no zero, $u>0$ or $u<0$ there, but then $z_0$ is a local minimum or maximum and that is impossible for non constant harmonic functions

Comment: Could it be that the maximum principle for harmonic and holomorphic functions isn't exaclty the same ? That $z_0$ can't be a local minimum or maximum follows from the mean value property, but in Wikipedia this statement is a conclusion of the maximum principle for harmonic functions, which in my textbook is defined analogous to the one for the holomorphic functions but the maximum principle for holomorphic functions states that a minimum is allowed if the image of this minimum is zero. For harmonic functions this can't be. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: For real harmonic functions (real is crucial here as holomorphic  functions can never be real unless constant) there is both a maximum and minimum principle for the function itself not its modulus like in the holomorphic case

Comment: I am a bit confused. I know that for real harmonic functions there is both a maximum and minimum principle for the function itself not it's modulus. Aside from that the maximumprinciple for harmonic and holomorphic functions is defined analogous. But my question is about the minimum principle. For non constant holomorphic functions it is allowed that the function has a minimum according to his modulus only if this minimum is a zero of the function. For harmonic functions such a minimum can never happen on the domain but than the harmonic function somehow can't have zeros.... which is strange.

Comment: Real harmonic functions generally  have lots  (uncountable many living on piecewise  smooth curves) of zeroes as zeroes cannot be isolated as the problem here shows; the zeroes of a holomorphic  function are isolated (a good exercise is to look at $z^2$ for which the real and imaginary  parts are $x^2-y^2, 2xy$ and see the zeroes of those near the zero of the holomorphic  function)